# Javascript Show thankyou modal after model submit

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

Hi i have model with feedback form. After model submit should show another thank you model also need to store local storage. Help me.

```
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="popUpToggle();" id="myModal2" >
<div class="form_fields feedbackfield">
<textarea id="txtMessage" name="txtMessage" rows="5" class="form-control contact-input" placeholder="Message *" required></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form_fields">
<input type="submit" class="contact-submit" name="SUBMIT" value="SUBMIT">
</div>
</form>
</div>

<div id="myModal4" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">                    
                <div class="popupHead3">
                   Thank you for your feedback    
                </div>    
      </div>
```

Javascript :

```
setTimeout(function() {
            if(localStorage.getItem("modalPopup")){$("#myModal2").modal('hide');}
            else{$('#myModal2').modal('show');}

        }, 5000);

        function popUpToggle(){         
            localStorage.setItem("modalPopup", "commit");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `AJAX` for `form` `submit` and then use

```
$('#myModal4').modal({show: 'true'});
```

Comment: How can i do that..? i gave popUpToggle() as onSubmit

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
$("#myModal2").submit(function(){
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: /* submit url or form action url */,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(d){
      /* do here what you want to do */

      $("#myModal4").modal({show: "true"});
    },
    dataType: "JSON"
  });
});
```